# How to put data in table column from another column list when select items?

Tags: php, html

I want to select item/s from a column and write it into a file when clicked, to appear in another column where file is included.

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%"><p><strong>FULL LIST</strong></p>
        <span>type 1</span>
        <span>type 2</span>
        <span>type 3</span>
        <span>type 4</span>
        <span>etc...</span>


        </td>
        <td width="50%"><p><strong>SELECTED</strong></p><?php include 'list.inc'?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The file 'list.inc' is updated when click on "type 1" etc.. everytime append a new string clicked, and when click on item on "SELECTED" column, should delete this one.

Comment: where exactly is your problem now? (and what does `list.inc` do?)

Comment: I'm searching a way to write on file list.inc the <span> elements content when clicked, so that they can be displayed in the second column, I do not know if it is the right approach.

Comment: no, it doesn't seem to be the right approach. When <span> is clicked, list.inc will have been executed long ago. Either use a form or an ajax call.

Comment: yes but page could be refreshed without problems.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help u

```js
$("document").ready(function()
{ 
 $("#c1 , #c2").on("click", "span", function()
 {
     trnf($(this))
 });
});

function trnf(eo)
{
 var po=$(eo).parent().prop("id")
 
 var tn=$(eo).prop("tagName");
 var val=$(eo).html();
 var ele="<"+tn+">"+val+"</"+tn+">";
 $(eo).remove();
 
 if(po=="c1")
 {$("#c2").append(ele);}
 else if(po=="c2")
 {$("#c1").append(ele);}
 
}
```

```css
span:hover{ background-color:#3CC}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td id="c1" style="background-color:#09F; width:200px; height:200px;">
    
        <span>type 1</span>
        <span>type 2</span>
        <span>type 3</span>
        <span>type 4</span>
        <span>type 5</span>
        <span>type 6</span>
        <span>type 7</span>
        <span>type 8</span>
        <span>type 9</span>
        <span>type 0</span>
    
    </td>
    <td id="c2" style="background-color:#99F; width:200px; height:200px;">
    
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Is it possible to save it in a determinated situation ? Other thing don't eliminate it on the left column when clicked (if click on item more times from the left column simply append it to other column)